# Unable to insert datas in the database using PDO

Tags: php, sql, forms, pdo, insert

I'd like to create a sign up form using PDO, but for an unknown reason, everything works excepted the writing into the database.

I'm quite stuck since Friday, and I'm kinda beginner in PDO, I believe I didn't saw something, but I can't tell what...
Any idea ?

```
    <?php

include('bdd.php'); //Allows to connect to the db from an other file

?>


<form name="inscription" action="confirmation.php" method="POST">
  <label for 'prenom'>Prénom: </label>
  <input type="text" name="prenom" required placeholder="Prénom"/>
  <label for 'nom'>Nom: </label>
  <input type="text" name="nom" required placeholder="Nom"/>
  <label for 'passe'>Mot de passe : </label>
  <input type="password" name="passe" required/>
  <label for 'confirm_passe'>Confirmez le mot de passe : </label>
  <input type="password" name="passe" required/>
  <label for 'email'>Email: </label>
  <input type="email" name="email"/ required placeholder="Adresse e-mail">
  <label for 'telephone'>Téléphone: </label>
  <input type="telephone" name="telephone"/ required placeholder="ex: 0123456789">
  <select name="fonction" id="fonction" required="required">
    <option value="">Selectionnez votre fonction</option>
    <option value="choix1">Présiden(e)</option>       
    <option value="choix2">Vice-Président(e)</option>
    <option value="choix3">Administrateur</option>
    <option value="choix4">Directeur/trice</option>
    <option value="choix5">Travailleur social</option>
    <option value="choix6">Secrétaire</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>



<?php


if(!empty($_POST['inscription'])){

if ( $_POST['confirm_passe'] != $_POST['passe'] ){
    echo "Passowords don't match";
}

$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO inscrits (prenom, nom, passe, telephone, email, fonction, droits) VALUES(:prenom, :nom, :passe, :telephone, :email, :fonction, 0)');
          $req->execute(array(
          'prenom' => $_POST['prenom'],
          'nom' => $_POST['nom'],
          'passe' => $_POST['passe'],
          'telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],      
          'email' => $_POST['email'],
          'fonction' => $_POST['fonction'],
          'droits' => $_POST['droits'],
          ));

}
?>
```

As you can see, I'm not english so please don't hesitate to ask any translation if you need to understand something :)

Thanks !

Comment: Could you make your `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, this will help display sql errors.

Comment: Are you storing password unencrypted in the database?! Please see http://www.phptherightway.com/#security ASAP

Answer (score 1):

The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL.

<kbd>[see doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)</kbd>

try this:

edit for error message:

set:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

in your bdd.php file for pdo error handling.

then

```
try{
   
  $req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO inscrits (prenom, nom, passe, telephone, email, fonction, droits) VALUES(:prenom, :nom, :passe, :telephone, :email, :fonction, 0)');

  $req->execute(array(
              ':prenom' => $_POST['prenom'],
              ':nom' => $_POST['nom'],
              ':passe' => $_POST['passe'],
              ':telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],      
              ':email' => $_POST['email'],
              ':fonction' => $_POST['fonction'],
              ':droits' => $_POST['droits']
              ));

}
 catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage ();
    die;
}
```

Comment: @user3628383 : did you check that?

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer, but there's still nothing in my DB with this code... Fact is I don't get any error and I get redirected where I wanted to. Is there a way for me to know where there's a problem?

Comment: Ok so I tried it and... no error. And still nothing in my database. It seems to ignore to check if both passwords are the same too.

Comment: did you copy my code? i have changed again.try it now

Comment: Yes, tried, tried and tried again, and still nothing... What on Earth is wrong with this code??

Comment: Do you have error_reporting enable and display_errors set to true?

Comment: I had it enabled but there still were no errors, so I eventually asked a friend of mine to check my code. He changed some properties in my database; for example my table "nom" was in INT, he switched it into VARCHAR, plus some little changes in the code, I don't remember everything (there were a lot of details that he changed), but you can already see some of them in a single sight.
Thank you all, my code was already way better after your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `:droits` (inside VALUES) inside `prepare()` function.

```
$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO inscrits (prenom, nom, passe, telephone, email, fonction, droits) VALUES (:prenom, :nom, :passe, :telephone, :email, :fonction, :droits)');
          $req->execute(array(
          'prenom' => $_POST['prenom'],
          'nom' => $_POST['nom'],
          'passe' => $_POST['passe'],
          'telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],      
          'email' => $_POST['email'],
          'fonction' => $_POST['fonction'],
          'droits' => $_POST['droits'],
          ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally managed to have something that is actually working, here is the code to have a sign up form that needs to be validated by an administrator if someone needs it in the future:

```
<?php

include('bdd.php'); //File that allows you to get connected to the server


if(!empty($_POST)){

  // Form has been submitted
  if ( $_POST['confirm_passe'] != $_POST['passe'] ) echo "Passwords don't match";

  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  try{
    //
    $req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO your_table (table1, table2, table3, table4, rights) VALUES(:value1, :value2, :value3, :value4, :rights)');

    $req->execute(array(
      ':value1' => $_POST['table1'],
      ':value2' => $_POST['table2'],
      ':value3' => $_POST['table3'],
      ':value4' => $_POST['table4'],      
      ':rights' => 0
    ));
    header('location:confirmation.php'); //Redirects you in a page that informs you that you are now registered
  }
   catch (PDOException $e) {
      print $e->getMessage ();
  }
}
?>
<!--And here goes the form that you can adapt at will -->
<form name="inscription" action="inscription.php" method="POST">
  <label for="prenom">Prénom: </label>
  <input type="text" name="prenom" required placeholder="Prénom"/>
  <label for 'nom'>Nom: </label>
  <input type="text" name="nom" required placeholder="Nom"/>
  <label for 'passe'>Mot de passe : </label>
  <input type="password" name="passe" required/>
  <label for="confirm_passe">Confirmez le mot de passe : </label>
  <input type="password" name="confirm_passe" required/>
  <label for 'email'>Email: </label>
  <input type="email" name="email"/ required placeholder="Adresse e-mail">
  <label for 'telephone'>Téléphone: </label>
  <input type="telephone" name="telephone"/ required placeholder="ex: 0123456789">
  <select name="fonction" id="fonction" required="required">
    <option value="">Selectionnez votre fonction</option>
    <option value="choix1">Présiden(e)</option>       
    <option value="choix2">Vice-Président(e)</option>
    <option value="choix3">Administrateur</option>
    <option value="choix4">Directeur/trice</option>
    <option value="choix5">Travailleur social</option>
    <option value="choix6">Secrétaire</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Thank you for your help !